# Protractor: get the pseudo element : placeholder css

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Does anyone have an idea how to get the css for placeholder in input tag in protractor test cases?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check below example.

Protactor:

`element(by.model('yourName')).getAttribute("placeholder").getCssValue("color")
.then(function(value){
      console.log("color value :: ", value)
});`

HTML:

```
<input id="input-search" ng-model="yourName" type="text" placeholder="Filter data" >
```

Comment: I need css not the content. Did you tried it for css ?